# UNNotificationServiceExtension sometimes doesn't run

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on an application which uses an UNNotificationServiceExtension. Most of the time (something like 90%) my extension runs correctly, makes a connection the the backend and then displays the notification. But seems like sometimes the extension doesn't run at all and the system displays the original message inside the notification. Why does this happen? All notifications definitely contain the mutable-content key set to 1.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue when was implementing `UNNotificationServiceExtension`. My problem was in time limitation that is given to load additional content

[Here is the link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension/1648229-didreceive)

> Your extension has a limited amount of time (no more than 30 seconds)
>   to modify the content and execute the contentHandler block. If you do
>   not execute that block in a timely manner, the system calls your
>   extension’s serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() method to give you one
>   last chance to execute the block. If you do not, the system presents
>   the notification’s original content to the user.

If you want ensure that it's the same issue, you can implement following method and change content in certain way

```
func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire()
```

By adding amount of seconds UNNotificationServiceExtension is alive, I found out that sometimes system don't give you even those 30 seconds.

Comment: At first I though the same, but after adding some logging I can see that the didReceive call is not being logged. So either the method is not called at all, or it terminates even before I can write a string to a file.